# How to target WinPhone and WinRT in the same project?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I have created a Visual Studio 2012 C++/CX project that targets both WinPhone 8 and WinRT. The solution can be downloaded [here (Hybrid.zip)](http://zoy.org/~sam/private/Hybrid.zip) if anyone is interested.

Unfortunately, it doesn’t work as expected with the solution platforms. Two platforms are working properly:

- If I select solution platform `ARM`, a native ARM WinPhone binary is built.
- If I select solution platform `x64`, a native 64-bit Windows binary is built.

However I have trouble with `Win32`. The Windows Phone SDK understands `Win32` as “WinPhone x86 binary for the simulator” whereas the Windows SDK understands `Win32` as “Windows x86 native binary”. The same project platform is used for two very different things!

I have tried creating a solution platform `WinPhoneEmu`. However, I have no idea how to create a *project* platform that will let me have two different platform configuration choices `Win32` and `WinPhoneEmu` that behave as I expect. How could I do that?

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory solution to this? I'm trying to target WP8 and Win32 with a single C++ codebase and would really like to not have to keep two solutions in sync manually.

Comment: @Tyr I must admit I gave up on WinRT after deciding the effort was not worth it. But we’ve migrated to VS2013 since then, and I should have a look to see whether there have been any changes with that regard.

Comment: Ah well. I've been avoiding VS2013 since it seems to break Win8.0 compatibility. Although I did see that it does provide something similar to what we're both after: a single solution containing multiple projects which share code and target different platforms. I would just much prefer to stick to 2012, if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is explicitly **not supported**. The primary reason being that the XAML syntax between WinRT and Phone is similar, but not exactly compatible (phone is Silverlight-ish, WinRT is some weird new thing).

The best way to target both is to have a total of 3 projects:

1. A portable class library targeting Phone and WinRT where all your logic goes
2. A UI layer for WinRT that links to the PCL
3. A UI layer for Phone that links to the PCL

Comment: It does work. The same C++ code (in the solution I link to) compiles to a properly working WinPhone binary and a properly working WinRT binary, with very few `#ifdef`. I have trouble with the Win32 platform setup because both SDKs want to handle it.

Comment: By the way, the reason I do not wish to use several projects is that this is going to be applied to a solution of about 60 projects. Going to 180 projects is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, in this situation you need to select both platform (x86, x64, ARM) and target (Device, Emulator) manually. You can do it easily by adding platform selector in Visual Studio toolbar. Tools -> Customize -> Commands -> Toolbar -> Standard, then add 'Solution Platforms" command. This is a combo box with x86, x64, ARM, Any CPU, etc. Then you'll be able to select, say, x86 + Emulator WXGA for WP8 emulator, or x86 + Device for W8 device:

[image: See my screenshot]

... and here how it will look in VS after that:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer; unfortunately, the "Target" dropdown menu only lets the user select the *debugging* target and has no effect on the *build* target (*ie.* the binary platform such as WinPhone, Windows…).

Comment: I think this box will also change the build target, since you cannot debug WP8 software pretending it is actually W8. Do you have correct targets in that box? I mean both W8 and WP8?

Comment: Well from what I can see it doesn't change the build target (you can see for yourself using the small solution I link to in the question). I do have W8 and WP8 targets available, since the "x64" and "ARM" platforms work as expected (ie. using respectively W8 and WP8).